# PHP, pdo, how to insert NULL to mysql when the input is blank else the input value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is the table tbl_temp:

```
id(pri unique)      name(unique, null able)
1                   abc
2                   null
3                   eadf
4                   null
5                   null
```

this is the insert function:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_temp (id, name) values (:id, :name);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
$stmt->execute();
```

this is the view for the insert function

```
<from action='' method='post'>
      <input type='text' name='name'>
      <input type='submit' />
 </form>
```

now here if the value is blank for the input name, it should assign the null to bindParam->name but it's assigning the value of 0 here which is giving error of duplicate if it give null then it will be ok because mysql can have null on unique but not zero

Comment: -1, why?? can you please explain

Comment: This is a not a real code. 1. It contains syntax errors. 2. it contains no code that assigns 0 to name variable.

Comment: check if the fields are empty else insert the value or insert a null

Comment: is this your site, i mean it's belong to you.????

Comment: When I am telling you to post the real code, it is not my personal whim. I am just telling you the site rules. Care to read them yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set your `id` column to auto increment, second, change your statement to

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_temp (name) values (:name);"
```

if you dont use the id, why not auto increment it?

and finally, use it like this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_temp (name) values (:name);")
$name = $this->name;
if($name == ""){
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', null, PDO::PARAM_STR);
} else{
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}


$stmt->execute();
```

you dont have to change your table if you dont want, i just suggest to do it, but basically if you want to set null, just use `bindValue(':name', null, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: what does this autoincrement thing to do with the question?

Comment: I agree with Dima. In the question the id column is: `id(pri unique)`.  There doesn't seem to be a reason not to auto increment.

Comment: @misterManSam what if it's just a foreign key from other table? Either way, what does id to do with this question which is about name field?

Comment: that was just a suggestion, if its foreign key, it shouldnt be named `id`, i said at the end of my answer that its just a suggestion

Comment: I'm sure OP would clarify if needed. Amazingly, there are people out there who are still learning and can improve with extra advice ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$name = $this->name;
if(empty($name)){
    $name = null;
}
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_temp (id, name) values (:id, :name)");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->execute;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL(5.6+) has a function `NULLIF(a,b)` where if a = b then it returns NULL, otherwise it returns `a`.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (123,NULLIF('$field',''),'xyz')
```

if the $field variable is empty (`''`) it will return NULL, otherwise $field

You can do it manually like `CASE WHEN '$field'='' THEN NULL ELSE '$field' END` or even

```
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $this->name?:null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

(note the above examples are not escaped, and unsafe, but just an example of use)